# Remove JQuery validationEngine from the form

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form with 3 submit buttons. Only 1 will do the form validation other 2 must just submit the form without validation. I have the code but it works anyway for all 3 buttons and I only need 1 to be validating the form.

```
$(function() {
        $('#formID').validationEngine();
    });
```

Comment: Do you have 3 forms with id="formID" ?
Id's are unique in html, make them unique and the bind the jquery to the form you want to validate

Comment: Yes I do have an ID for each form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works for me

```
        $("#buttonId1").click(function(){
            $('#formId').validationEngine('hideAll');
            $('#formId').validationEngine('detach');
            $('#formId').validationEngine('attach');
            if($("#formId").validationEngine('validate'))
                return true;
            else
                return false;                
        });

        $("#buttonId2").click(function(){
            $('#formId').validationEngine('hideAll');
            $('#formId').validationEngine('detach');
            return true;                
        });

        $("#buttonId3").click(function(){
            $('#formId').validationEngine('hideAll');
            $('#formId').validationEngine('detach');
            return true;                
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is exactly what you need:

```
    $("#buttonId").click(function(){
         $('#formId').validationEngine();
     });

    $('#otherButtonId').click(function(){
        $('#formId').submit();
     });
```

The first validates the form and the second simply submits it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that the inline validation will still occur if you tab through the form fields, even though you would not want to do the validation when the user clicks one of the other submit buttons.

As an alternative to Jorge's suggestion, you could instantiate the validationengine on document ready as normal, and then detach the validationengine when one of the other buttons is clicked. You may also need to hide any prompts that are showing if you are submitting via Ajax and not leaving the screen.

```
$("#otherButtonId1").click(function(){
    // $('#formId').validationEngine('hideAll');
    $('#formId').validationEngine('detach');
 });

$('#otherButtonId2').click(function(){
    $('#formId').validationEngine('detach');
 });
```

~Cyrix

Comment: Actually, you can turn off inline checking if you want. By default it validates on blur of the field, but you can get it to validate on submit of the form using the validationEventTrigger:
    $('#formId').validationEngine({validationEventTrigger: 'submit'});